# Python | Creating a Hardware Array

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

I'm still a newbie in Python so please bear with me. I'm originally from C++ and C# and I'm still getting a hang of this new language.

I'm currently using Python for Data Structures. I'm using the textbook by Rance Necaise (Data Structures and Algorithms using Python). Arrays in Python still confuse me a little.

Here's a code segment I couldn't understand based on the book.

```
import ctypes

ArrayType = ctypes.c_int * 5
slots = ArrayType()
```

According to the book, slots is basically like a pointer

My question is what is the object type of ArrayType and why is there a constructor like function call ArrayType() on the next line? How do these statements actually make a pointer-like object slots?

Comment: All names in Python are references to objects.

Comment: So ArrayType is an object of what type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayType` doesn't create a pointer, it creates an object.

In Python, all names are references to objects, so `slots` is a reference to an object (in C++ terms, references are essentially pointers which can never be null.)

See [the `ctypes` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#arrays) about Arrays.

The type of `c_int` is a `PyCSimpleType`:

```
>>> import ctypes

>>> type(ctypes.c_int)
_ctypes.PyCSimpleType
```

The type of `ArrayType` in your example is `PyCArrayType`:

```
>>> ArrayType = ctypes.c_int * 5
>>> type(ArrayType)
_ctypes.PyCArrayType
```

`PyCArrayType`is a class which can create objects. The kind of array it creates is `c_long_Array_5` which can only hold 5 values maximum:

```
>>> ArrayType(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
IndexError: invalid index
```

If you create the array with fewer than 5 values they will default to zero:

```
>>> slots = ArrayType(1, 2, 3)
>>> list(slots)
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
```

So, your example will create an array initialised to zeroes:

```
>>> list(ArrayType())
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```